# Visual Studio 2012 variable font color reverts to black from user-selected color

Tags: c++, fonts, colors

I am rather new to using Visual Studio and I am attempting to use a color scheme that is very similar to Sublime Text 2 as I enjoy the highlighting of this text editor.

I have downloaded the Sublime Text Theme from [here](http://studiostyl.es/schemes/sublime-2).

When I import the theme, the colors change except for the variable names and the std namespace.  Those revert to black for some inexplicable reason.  I have tried installing other themes/color schemes and all have the aforementioned problem.  I have attempted to go into options and change the font color for variables/namespaces to the desired color.  It will revert to black as soon as I leave options.

I have opened and closed VS 2012, rebooted my computer, and attempted the use of other .cpp files with no avail.

I can make the colors display properly by typing a character on line one and moving the `#include <iostream>` down a line.  You can see the difference in the attached photo.  Any thoughts on what is causing this or how to fix the problem?

PS, I can't add the photo to my post as a new member, so [here's the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxezv.jpg) to imgur.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution to this problem.
For some strange reason the theme is not imported correctly.
You can manually change the color of the "c++ Local variables" and the "c++ namespace" color by going to options -> enviroment -> fonts and colors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The way I solved it was by changing the theme from light to dark.

Check this thread to see how:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9596223/1426601