# Visual Studio 2012 Express Desktop & Color Theme Editor Extension

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have recently installed VS2012 Express Desktop and Express Web. I have to say I am somewhat lacking in enthusiasm for the new dark and light themes. With that in mind, I have tracked down and attempted to install the [Visual Studio 2012 Color Theme Editor](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/366ad100-0003-4c9a-81a8-337d4e7ace05).

I have installed and used this successfully on my office machine (which is running a Premium edition of Visual Studio 2012), however the installation fails on Express editions.

Is this extension simply not supported in express editions, or is there an alternative for managing themes in VS2012 Express?

Comment: http://alinconstantin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/using-color-themes-with-visual-studio.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change themes, etc. on Visual Studio 2012 \*Express\* Desktop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12649715/change-themes-etc-on-visual-studio-2012-express-desktop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to jmoerdyk for this link...got it all working perfectly!

http://alinconstantin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/09/using-color-themes-with-visual-studio.html