# Cannot see VS2012 splitters

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Anyone else having this issue - the splitters in VS2012 are the same gray shade as all of the rest of the scroll bars and other panels next to them. It's driving me crazy hunting for them each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried changing the theme?

[How can I switch themes in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594433/how-can-i-switch-themes-in-visual-studio-2012)

```
Tools --> Options --> Environment --> General
```

That page also contains links to theme extensions that might help if the default themes have this problem for you.

Comment: Yes, that's it. There are three themes, and the Blue does the the trick. Nice contrasty splitter. Thanks!

Comment: Just adding with the theme editor in that link, I still couldn't find the splitter. In WPF it's called a GridSplitter, and VS is built on WPF, but I don't see it there under this or splitters. Maybe it's a window border or background or something. If anyone knows please post up.