# how to change the color of variables in VScode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, color-scheme

I started learning python recently. I use vscode and i really hate the default variable color in vscode(white) i want to change it to something colorful. I tried searching online most of them say to edit in `settings.json`. I couldn't figure out how.

edit : i edited my `settings.json` to this

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "c:\\Users\\Kakshipth\\Documents\\coding\\py\\virtualauto\\Scripts\\python.exe",
    "code-runner.respectShebang": false,
    
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "variables": "#1100ff"
     },
}
```

but still the color for variables did not change

Comment: Try checking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724696/make-vscode-variables-have-colour

Comment: i saw that post, but  i have no idea how to get into `settings.json`, i go to `prefrences -> settings -> extenstions` only to find that there are multiple settings.json files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I switch themes in Visual Studio 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594433/how-can-i-switch-themes-in-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: @dh762 the question is not about changing the whole color theme. It is about changing the default color with which VS Code marks variables, which is only one small part in the whole scheme. Sure, it would solve the problem, but it seems that OP is ok with the rest of the color theme, just not with this one particular thing.

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio Code, use `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type `settings.json` to the field that shows up. After you type it, it should give you the settings.json file as the first search result. Just click on it and the file should open. Once you open the settings.json file, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47724696/make-vscode-variables-have-colour) to see how to change the color of variables.

Comment: thanks, i did you what you said and posted the updated `settings.json` in the question above. I reloded the window but still i get white color for variables

Answer (score 2):

You can try with command line:

```
 "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "variable",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#c70a39",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```